# Caddy server HTTPS redirect causes "too many redirects"

Tags: ssl, redirect, caddy, caddyfile

My web host already provides SSL configured on my domain so I want to use Caddy server to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS using the "Redirect only if the forwarded protocol is HTTP" [example from the docs](https://caddyserver.com/docs/redir). The issue is that the browser is unable to render the page my caddy config. Going to the URL shows the error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly. An error occurred during a connection to ****.
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. (Firefox)
>
> This page isn’t working **** redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (Chrome)

This is my Caddyfile

```
0.0.0.0:{$PORT} {
  bind {$ADDRESS}
  proxy / 0.0.0.0:{$API_PORT}
  redir 301 {
    if {>X-Forwarded-Proto} is http
    /  https://{host}{uri}
  }
}
```

My host provides $PORT=8080 as the main entry point for web traffic so I started my NodeJS app to listen on $API_PORT=9090. My expectation is that Caddy receives all traffic on port `0.0.0.0:8080` and redirects all non-HTTPS requests to my NodeJS app on port `0.0.0.0:9090`. I like this idea because I would prefer not to put networking logic in the app but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Caddy and NodeJS are on the same machine.

Comment: Can you provide your entire caddyfile?

Comment: that is my entire file

Comment: Can you provide in your question more information?  Are the hosts you are redir to on the same machine? How many hosts ? Can you add a log directive  to see what is being requested?  WHy are you proxying all requests back to itself?  What is {$PORT} what is {$API_PORT}?  Any more information is always helpful

Comment: Thanks @TobyAllen, I've added more information about my setup. Please let me know if I missed something out.

Comment: Can you ask your question on https://caddy.community our forum, I think you’ll get more help there.  I think you should simplify until you have something working then make more complicated. There are too many unknowns in this setup and no logging

Comment: We have something called 'port_in_redirect' directive in nginx which strips of the port number which doesn't cause ambiguity in application. I believe this kind of directive is missing in caddy